# I can return an unevaluated list as a vector using the quoted form with 'vec' in Clojure, how can I then make use of the function reference?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

This was the product of trial and error in the 4clojure REPL, and this may be a peculiarity of that in particular,

Intended behaviour:

```
(vec (repeat 10 0))
=> [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Using the quoted form I get this result:

```
(vec '(repeat 10 0))
=> [repeat 10 0]
```

This is puzzling.

I can evaluate this sequence by converting it back to a list and using 'eval', but what exactly is 'repeat' here in the return value? Can I access it apart from the other members of the sequence, using `(first [repeat 10 0])` for example, and call it? In the 4Clojure REPL, `((first (vec '(repeat 10 0))) 10 0)` returns `0`.

Answer (score 2):

Expression `'(repeat 10 0)` returns quoted list ([`quote`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/quote) stops evaluation). `repeat` won't be function, but symbol:

```
(map type '(repeat 10 0))
=> (clojure.lang.Symbol java.lang.Long java.lang.Long)
```

You can use `first` and get only this symbol, but if you want to call it, you have to convert it into function with [`resolve`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/resolve):

```
((resolve (first '(repeat 10 0))) 5 0)
=> (0 0 0 0 0)
```

If you will use `vector`, each element will be evaluated before vector is created:

```
[repeat 10 0]
=> [#object[clojure.core$repeat 0x2a4d87a "clojure.core$repeat@2a4d87a"] 10 0]

(map type [repeat 10 0])
=> (clojure.core$repeat java.lang.Long java.lang.Long)
```

And in this case, you don't even need `resolve`:

```
((first [repeat 10 0]) 5 0)
=> (0 0 0 0 0)
```

And why does `((first (vec '(repeat 10 0))) 10 0)` returns `0`? Because this expression `('repeat 10 0)` doesn't call function [`repeat`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/repeat).

This expression calls symbol on something. You can do that, symbols implement `Ifn`, so they are *"callable"*. You can check that with [`ifn?`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/ifn_q):

```
(ifn? 'repeat)
=> true
```

As you can see, not only functions are *"callable"*, but also symbols, keywords, vectors, maps or sets.

When symbol is called on something, function actually called is [`get`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/get). So, meaning of `('repeat 10 0)` is this: search for `'repeat` in object `10` and if you don't find it, return `0`. See this in more examples:

```
('repeat {'foo 1 'bar 2})
=> nil

('repeat {'foo 1 'bar 2} 0)
=> 0

('repeat {'foo 1 'bar 2 'repeat 3})
=> 3

('repeat #{'foo 'bar})
=> nil

('repeat #{'foo 'bar} 0)
=> 0

('repeat #{'foo 'bar 'repeat})
=> repeat
```

Answer (score 1):

When you quoted the list `(repeat 10 0)` the *symbol* `repeat` is returned instead of `clojure.core$repeat`.

When you invoke a symbol as a function, [this implementation of symbol explains what happens](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Symbol.java#L131) In your case you are invoking the symbol `repeat` and passing it two arguments `10` and `0`. The second argument `0` is the `notFound` value seen in the implementation linked just above.

If you call `resolve` on the symbol `repeat`, you could use the return value (`#'clojure.core/repeat`) to invoke.

Answer (score 0):

If you quote something (with `'`), you quote everything inside it.  This
is opting out of resolving functions etc.

So you get from `'(repeat 10 0)` a list, that contains a symbol `repeat`
and the number 10 and 0.

To be clear here: the `repeat` you see there is *not* the function.
It's just a symbol.  If you want the function from it, you would have to
`resolve` it.  If you want to get hold just of the function, you would
not quote the list.  And there is always the option to `eval`.

```clj
user=> (def x '(repeat 10 0))
#'user/x
user=> (-> x first type)
clojure.lang.Symbol
user=> (type repeat)
clojure.core$repeat
```